# History of filter and ultrafilter

Tags: mathematics

The history of filters and ultrafilters is a bit of a mess. According to some authors, the concept of ultrafilter was first introduced by Cartan (1937). According to some authors, the concept of ultrafilter was first introduced by Riesz (1908). In some sources, the theorem that every filter is contained in an ultrafilter was given by Tarski in 1930. I am wondering which mathematicians gave the concepts such as filter, ultrafilter and filter basis in which year and in which sources. I searched many sources, but I couldn't have a clear idea.

Answer (score 1):

According to Bourbaki, Topologie, I, historical essay, filters and ultrafilters
were introduced by H. Cartan, Theorie de filtres et ultrafiltres, C. R., 205 (1937) 595-598 et 777-779.
On my opinion, Bourbaki can be trusted on this matter.

Comment: Engelking says filters first appeared in Riesz https://imgur.com/a/frDUq3A

Comment: Can you give an exact reference on Riesz (1908)?

Comment: F. Riesz. Stetigkeitsbegriff und abstrakte Mengenlehre, Atti del IV Congresso Intemazionale dei Matematici, Roma 1908, vol. II, Roma 1909, 18-24.

Comment: https://docplayer.org/50780054-F-riesz-stetigkeitsbegriff-und-abstrakte-mengenlehre.html

Comment: @Mehmet Onat: thanks. Not a single formula in the paper! And unfortunately, I do not read German...

Comment: I dont understand too :). But here are some comments by Brian M. Scoot https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/530752/etymology-of-the-term-filter/530799?noredirect=1#comment9900463_530799

Comment: https://www.google.com.tr/books/edition/New_Infinitary_Mathematics/n_6LEAAAQBAJ?hl=tr&gbpv=1&dq=concepts+of+filter+and+ultrafilter+was+%C4%B1ntroduced+by+Riesz&pg=PA111&printsec=frontcover

Comment: https://www.jstor.org/stable/27642389

Answer (score 1):

As for the history of filters and ultrafilters, Gregory H. Moore devotes some pages to this subject in his rich in information book *Zermelo's Axiom of Choice. Its Origins, Development & Influence*, Dover, 2013 (republication of the edition   by Springer-Verlag, 1982).

Moore too attributes the definition of *filter* and *ultrafilter* to Cartan.

Below some passages from the book:

> In the same year that Čech's article appeared [1937], two
> generalizations of convergence - directed sets and filters - were
> developed independently of each other in the United States and France.
> A few years later, these two generalizations would provide a way to
> represent compactness as well. In 1922 the first approach had been
> formulated jointly by two mathematicians, E.H. Moore of the University
> of Chicago and H.L. Smith of the University of Philippines. [...] Only
> in 1937 did Birkhoff render this approach suitable for topology. [...]
> Meanwhile Henri Cartan proposed to the Paris Academy of Science a
> different but related generalization of convergence: filters.$^1$
> [...] A central notion was that of maximal filter, or, as Cartan
> termed it, an ultrafilter.
>
> [...] By means of the Well-Ordering Theorem and transfinite induction,
> Cartan formulated and proved a fundamental result later known as the
> Ultrafilter Theorem:
>
> *Every filter can be extended to an ultrafilter.*$^2$
>
> From this proposition he deduced that a Hausdorff space *E* is compact
> if and only if every ultrafilter on *E* has a limit point.[...]
>
> In the 1940 Cartan's characterization of compactness enabled Bourbaki
> to give a proof of Tychonoff's Theorem, restricted to Haussdorff
> spaces, by using ultrafilters rather than complete accumulation
> points.[...]
>
> Moreover Bourbaki developed filters as a device suitable for defining
> a topological space, and, in particular, for characterizing pointwise
> convergence  [...]
>
> Over the next two decades, filters served French topologist as their
> preferred form of generalized convergence, while Americans confined
> themselves to directed sets.[...] Eventually, mathematicians
> recognized that these two methods of convergence (filters and directed
> sets) were essentially equivalent. However, to establish this
> equivalence, the Axiom came into play. (Moore, pp. 249-241).

$^1$  <sup>Cartan, Henri, “Théorie des filtres”, Comptes Rendus Hebdomandaires des Séances de l’Académie des Sciences, Paris, **205**, 595-598</sup>

$^2$  <sup>Cartan, Henri, “Filters and ultrafilters”, Comptes Rendus Hebdomandaires des Séances de l’Académie des Sciences, Paris, **205**, 777-779</sup>

Answer (score 1):

See also:

Leopold Vietoris, dissertation "Stetige Mengen" published in Monatsheft Math., vol. 81, 173-202 in 1921

He uses the German word "Kranz" for what we now call "filter base".